# Printing the nth range with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I can print the braceted lines in the file a

```
first
[
third
fourth
]
sixth
[
eighth 
]
tenth
```

by doing

```
% <a sed -n '/\[/,/\]/p'
```

which prints

```
[
third
fourth
]
[
eighth
]
```

But what if I want only the second match, ie. the last three lines?

Answer (score 2):

Easier to do with `awk`, assuming the blocks defined by `[` and `]` do not themselves contain `[` or `]` inside the block

```
$ awk -v b=2 '/\[/{c++} c==b; /]/ && c==b{exit}' ip.txt
[
eighth 
]
```

- `-v b=2` variable to specify which block is required
- `/\[/{c++}` increment counter if line matches starting condition
- `c==b;` print input record if counter is equal to block required
- `/]/ && c==b{exit}` exit on matching ending condition

another way to write this:

```
awk -v b=2 '/\[/{c++} c==b{print $0; if(/]/) exit}' ip.txt
```

Comment: Separating rules with semicolon makes it more readable (missing after `/\[/{c++}`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n '/^\[/h; /^\[/,/^\]/H; ${x;s/^\[\n//;p;}' file
[
eighth
]
```

Annotated `sed` script (assumes `-n`):

```
/^\[/h;         # replace hold space with this line
/^\[/,/^\]/H;   # append these lines to hold space with embedded newlines
${              # at last line of input
    x;          # swap in the hold space
    s/^\[\n//;  # delete the first "[" and the newline following it
    p;          # print
}
```

That is, whenever we find a line that starts with `[`, clear the hold space by copying the line there.  Then keep appending lines to the hold space until we find the corresponding line that starts with `]`.

At the end, we will have a hold space with one `[` too many, so delete that (and the embedded newline after it) before printing the data.

Comment: This will print the last block and not the second. In this dataset, the second block happens to be the last is why it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` editor, we can perform it as follows:

```
sed -ne '                    ;# "-n" suppresses autoprint of pattern space
    /^\[/!d                  ;# skip lines that donot begin a fresh block
    :a;$!N;/\n]/!ba          ;# keep appending lines to pattern space until end of block
    G                        ;# append our makeshift counter (hold space) to pattern spc
    s/\n\{2\}$//p            ;# only when counter had 2 chars in it, we print block
    /\n$/!q                  ;# target block, 2nd block has been printed so quit 
    x;s/$/\n/;x              ;# target block not reached, so increment
' input.file
```

---

with `Perl`, we can use the `...` operator in tandem with the boolean $k == 2, indicating that we have reached the intended target block and need to print it.

```
perl -lne 'print if /^\[/ && ++$k == 2 ... /^]/' input.file
```

Comment: I've refactored your script [a bit](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/e3c366893ba8b6c07385f6822a3ba904). Nothing major. Switched to extended regexps. Make it more strict about separators (`/^\[$/`). Supposedly unneeded condition before `N` (`$!N`). And not sure why you use `;#` for comments.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
nl -bp'\[' -s ' ' input.txt | sed -n '/ *2 \[/,/\]/p' | cut -c 8-
```

input.txt:

```
first
[
third
fourth
]
sixth
[
eighth 
]
tenth
```

standard output:

```
[
eighth 
]
```

## Explanation

1. `nl -bp` can add line numbers based on specific pattern.
2. Here we use white space as separator instead of tab by `nl -s ' '` because `\t` is not portable in `sed`.

```bsh
nl -bp'\[' -s ' ' input.txt
```

```
       first
     1 [
       third
       fourth
       ]
       sixth
     2 [
       eighth 
       ]
       tenth
```

3. By default, `nl` prepend 6 characters for padding, you can remove first 7 characters by `cut -c 8-`.